# Ubuntu - can't see my folders

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

First question here - please do let me know if I'm missing any necessary details / any structures and protocols that I may not be adhering to.

I've downloaded Ubuntu (version 18.04) on my Windows 10 Pro laptop, however, I can't quite figure out where my Downloads folder is. I'm attempting to install cuDNN, which effectively requires that I download files and then install them via my Ubuntu terminal.

From what I've seen in other answers / posts online, I should be able to execute the command `cd ~/Downloads` to get there, but this generates the message "No such file or directory".

Hopefully the attached screenshots are helpful - do let me know if there's any additional screenshots that would help.

[image: Ubuntu Terminal screenshot]

**EDITS:** 
Additional screenshot showing the contents of the etc/skel folder as requested

[Ubutntu terminal screenshot of etc/skel folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Qva.png)

Additional screenshot showing the command file /home/hasan/Downloads

[Ubuntu terminal screenshot of file /home/hasan/Downloads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM69j.png)

[Ubuntu terminal screenshot of file /home/hasan/Downloads (re-opened terminal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0TRk.png)

Comment: Did you actually install Ubuntu or are you running it as a live image?

Comment: Hi Nasir - what's the best method of checking this? I installed it by downloading the Ubuntu app via the Microsoft store, and enabling "Windows Subsystem for Linux" within the Windows Settings

Comment: What is in the `/etc/skel` directory?

Comment: I've edited the post with a screenshot of the etc/skel contents - hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0TRk.png]

Start with the last line in the above screenshot, and after the `$` terminal prompt type `cd Downloads`. According to the screenshot your current directory is the home directory of the user that you are logged in with, so the command `ls` should show the Downloads directory and `cd Downloads` should change directories to it.

You can make a Downloads directory if none exists with this command:

```
mkdir Downloads
```

or even:

```
mkdir Documents Downloads Music Pictures Videos
```

Comment: Hi Karel - thanks for your reponse. As shown in the screenshot in the question, there's no folder called "Downloads" in /home/hasan/

Comment: Hi Karel - post updated with a screenshot showing the command. I've run this both with and without sudo su in case this was causing issues - looks to be the same output either way

Comment: I'm most likely misinterpreting your comment - but I think what you're referring to is the second half of my screenshot (after I'd typed the "exit" command). However, for completeness, I've closed the terminal, re-opened and executed the command again and appended an additional screenshot. Let me know if this helps

Comment: @Hasan Did you actually `mkdir Downloads` in your `/home/hasan` folder to create the `Downloads` directory inside.